# How can I assign a dynamic ID value to a label?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I have the following code:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='competitor' style='background: ".$row['Colour'].";'>";
    echo "<div class='competitorname'>".$row['CompetitorName']."</div><br>";
    echo "<div class='competitorscore' id='".$row['CompetitorID']."'>";
        echo"<label id='".$row['CompetitorName']."'></label></div>";
        echo "<input type='button' value='Increase' id='inc' onclick='incNumber()'/>";
        echo "<input type='button' value='Decrease' id='dec' onclick='decNumber()'/>";
}
```

The code is linked to the following script:

```
var i = 0;

function incNumber() {
    if (i < 10) {
        i++;
    } else if (i = 10) {
        i = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = i;
}

function decNumber() {
    if (i > 0) {
        --i;
    } else if (i = 0) {
        i = 10;
    }
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = i;
}
```

The code creates a scoreboard. It creates a div for each team with a score for that team.

The problem I'm having is that the "Increase" and "Decrease" buttons are increasing and decreasing the score on only one team (the first one). This is because the script is looking for the label with the id='display' and linking every button to that one.

My question is, how can I create a different ID for each team that works with the script so that each increase/decrease button is linked to a different team?

Comment: but why do you need to assign unique ids to a label at first place? Do you need to fetch label of a competitor at any point in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CompetitorID` as a parameter to the increment and decrement functions to tell it which row to affect. Your label:

```
<label id='display".$row['CompetitorID']."'></label>
```

Your button `onclick` event:

```
onclick='incNumber(".$row['CompetitorID'].")'
```

Then your JavaScript:

```
function incNumber(id) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i++;
    } else if (i = 10) {
        i = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('display' + id).innerHTML = i;
}
```

**Edit**

For the issue in the comments, echo a hidden field which stores the value for each team:

```
<input type='hidden' id='score".$row['CompetitorID']."' value='0'/>
```

Then remove the global `var i = 0;` and modify your functions similar to this:

```
function incNumber(id) {
        // Get the score input
        var scoreField = document.getElementById('score' + id);
        // Get the value
        var i = parseInt(scoreField.value);
        if (i < 10) {
            i++;
        } else if (i = 10) {
            i = 0;
        }
        // Set the visual score
        document.getElementById('display' + id).innerHTML = i;
        // Set the score input to the new score
        scoreField.value = i;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked wonders. Last issue I'm having is that when I apply your fix, pressing the button adds/subtracts from the last score (ie the last copy of i). eg. If I press increase 5 times on competitor 1, and then press it once on competitor 2, it'll set competitor 2 to 6 instead of 1. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$row['CompetitorID']` value which is, presumably, unique. Append that to the IDs you are using.